# How do you make image recenter itself after window resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the [Adirondack](https://adirondack-demo.squarespace.com/) template from Squarespace, there's this other responsive feature where if you resize the window horizontally, the main photo doesn't seem to scale, but it instead recenters itself based on the window size. I included a GIF of what I'm trying to articulate below.

How could I go about replicating that effect? All my attempts have just resulted in the entire image scaling instead of just recentering itself.

[image: image resizing example]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: well image is resizing......probably max width, but just looking at the source would tell you that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the gif, it looks like the image does indeed scale itself down. i.e. she is shrinking.

Answer (score 1):

The effect depends on the proportions of the source image, but something like this, right?

```
.img {
  background: url(https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/beautiful-sunset-images-196063.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jcpzqx5h/6/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is css @media rules.

Here is a link to a [w3school page about @media rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). They have a good example on their website of a dynamic page like the one in your gif with code included.

Also CSS percentage values in width property of elements will help when doing stuff like this.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!